# Чтение файла выбранного в ListBox

Tags: c#

Имеется listbox, в который отображаются названия файлов с папки на диске C

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Scripts");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
```

Так вот. При выборе элемента в данном listbox-е хочу переносить текст из него в textbox, а значит открыть выбранный .txt файл, прочитать текст и "вывести" его в textbox. У меня это реализовано немного так скажем костыльно - приходится копировать все текстовики в папку к экзешнику, так как при выборе элемента в listbox-е получаю ошибку с текстом "не могу найти элемент **путь_к_.exe/имя_файла.txt**". Можно ли как - то при выборе файла в listbox-е читать текст с него именно в C:\Scripts, а не с папки с экзешником? На данный момент ивент с листбоксом выглядит так :

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedscrpt = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(selectedscrpt);
        fastColoredTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(selectedscrpt);
    }
```

Comment: Да просто пишите. Вот в таком выражении `File.Exist("text.txt");` провериться путь: "папка с exe/text.txt". Думаю это оно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... File.ReadAllText(File.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Scripts", selectedscrpt));
```